# tabs in verticaly middle page or after div element in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic2-tabs

I want to implement tabs in the middle of page or after div in ionic 2.
I have tried top and bottom.it successfully set to bottom or top but i want to set it after div. Can anyone done like this before?

in ts file:

```
 tab1Root = tabPage1;
 tab2Root = tabPage2;
 tab3Root = tabPage3;
 tab4Root = tabPage4;
```

My Html Code:

```
<ion-content>
<div class="row">
  <img src="../../assets/img/paneer_matar.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<ion-tabs  #ionTabs [scrollable-tabs]="ionTabs" selectedIndex="1">
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="tabPage1"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="tabPage2"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="tabPage3"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="tabPage4"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```